# exe cannot find network path but debugging via Visual Studio works

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have a tool that was working for without issues for several years but all the sudden it's failing because it cannot find the network path it needs to access.

In the code I have a PathExists check like this

> [PathExists()][DefaultValue(@"\somebuildsnetworkpath\")] string buildPath

When the program tries executes the PathExists() check it fails with '\somebuildsnetworkpath\' is not an existing file or directory.

When I try debugging in Visual Studio, the program executes fine without issues.The bits should be the same so I'm confused as to what the difference might be and why all the sudden the exe is failing.

Comment: Are you running the exe as your user?

Comment: How are you launching the application when it fails?  Does debugging use a different working directory (Project properties → `Debug` → `Working directory`) than when you launch it without Visual Studio?

Comment: @JoePhillips I had the tool running as a scheduled task under my user name. This had worked fine for several years until now (no code changes at all). After it started failing I tried running the exe in a administrator command prompt and it still failed.

Comment: @BACON The Working directory field is blank so that should mean the default bin/Debug folder I assume. I'm also calling the exe directly from this bin/Debug folder.

Comment: Is it worth citing/tagging what that `PathExists` attribute is part of? And since you've mentioned that the path is a network path, are you sure nothing has changed with the network permissions for the user that the job runs as? And is the path hard coded or does it use environment variables (e.g. possible with [Clap.netcore](https://github.com/TV5Dev/CLAP.NETCore/blob/master/CLAP/Validation/PathExistsAttribute.cs)).

Comment: @Richardissimo PathExists is part of CLAP. I was planning on asking someone who knows more about networking than I do to be sure but not sure how permissions could be the issue since I should be using the same user account while in debug mode as well. Path is hard coded not through env variables.

Comment: Ah, good. Debugging as the same user that the task runs as will help. Is the network path specified with a network drive letter or UNC location? (UNC is more robust since it does not depend on the drive having been mapped, so try that if not using it already.)

Comment: uses a unc path like \\path\

Comment: So, to summarize, it fails when run from both elevated and non-elevated `Command Prompt`s as well as from a `Task Scheduler` task that previously worked?  The only place it works is when debugging in `Visual Studio`?  What about if you do `Start Without Debugging`?  And I assume your user is a member of the local `Administrators` group, so it's always the same user whether elevated or not?